# How is "ante" being used in "antelabeto" in Luke 1v54?

Tags: word-study

Some examples of "anti"...Luke 11v11 Here "anti" =instead of,substitution. The serpent is substituted for the fish...
1 Tim 2v6 antilytron=again substitution, Christ pays what we could not...
1 John 2v18 antichristos signifies an opponent to the Messiah.  .
Heb 6v16 antilogias=dispute, strife, antagonism.  .
Luke 1v54 "antelabeto" being translated in the E.S.V. as "He has helped His servant Israel", has neither substitution nor antagonism. So what is the force of "ante" here?

Comment: These should be taken word by word - there is no uniform consistency in Greek prefixes because some are attached to nouns or verbs in either the active, middle or passive voice which usually alters the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the OP regarding the similarity of the meaning and usage of αντελαβετο in Luke 1:54 to αντιλυτρον in I Timothy 2:6.

The meaning of *lambano* [Strong 2983](https://biblehub.com/greek/2983.htm) is 'to take' or to 'lay hold'. The prefix *anti-* in Greek [Strong 473](https://biblehub.com/greek/473.htm) has the force of 'over against' 'opposite' or 'in correspondence'. The meaning is not the same as our 'anti-' prefix in English.

So αντελαβετο in Luke 1:54 bears the concept of 'take hold in correspondence of'.

God has taken hold on his servant in correspondence of Israel, is the meaning.

And he has done so, 'in remembrance of his mercy'.

And he has done so 'as He spoke to our fathers'. God spoke to the fathers, and what God said was **'to Abraham and his seed for ever'**. That was the promise. That God's mercy was 'to Abraham and to his seed for ever'.

> Now to Abraham and his Seed were the promises made. He does not say, "And to seeds," as of many, but as of one, "And to your Seed," who is Christ.  Galatians 3:16 KJV.

For God said to Abraham :

> For all the land which thou seest, **to thee will I give it, and to thy seed for ever.** Genesis 13:15 KJV.

And, again :

> ... and I will give **unto thee, and to thy seed after thee,** the land ... Genesis 17:8 KJV.

Mary is quoting from Genesis when she says 'as he spoke to our fathers ...'.

- God has taken hold of his servant, in correspondence of Israel.
- In remembrance of his mercy.
- As he spoke to our fathers 'to Abraham and to his seed for ever'.

The 'seed' she speaks of is the servant (Christ, the singular seed). And he shall be 'taken hold of' - in correspondence of Israel or 'over against' Israel.

Due to God remembering his mercy, as he promised.

But Mary's meaning has a subtlety which I think does not warrant the idea of 'substitution' in this place. My own understanding of Mary's meaning is that she is referring to the conception (which had been announced to her). For '*sunlambano*' is the word that Gabriel had used to herald the conception.

So my own perception of Mary's reference to 'take hold in correspondence' is, initially, the conception within Mary not - yet - a matter of substitutionary atonement.

Comment: Nigel the meaning is not supposed to be the same as the English "anti". The Greek prefix αντε is the same as the English prefix "ante", e.g. an *anteroom* is a waiting room -- a "holding" room, if you like.

Comment: @ enegue I picture 2 sorts of "against". A. Two forces antagonistic to each other. B. A weak wall needing a buttress against it to hold it up. Here "against" is supportive and additional like clothes against the skin.

Comment: @enegue The English prefix 'ante' means preceding, which is _also_ not the meaning of the Greek prefix.

Comment: Well, one only sees what one wants to see. What is the **function** of a "preceding" room? Surely, as a "holding" area prior to a formal entry.

Comment: @ Nigel How about: If one sees a weak person down and laying hold of them lets them lean against oneself, we have against+ lay hold. He has helped [taken the weight] of His servant?